# What version of OpenGLES is iOS6 using?

Tags: xcode, opengl-es, ios6, version

What version of OpenGLES is iOS6 using?

Comment: -1 I think one minute on Google gives you the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the iOS Developer Library an implementation of both OpenGL ES 1.1 and OpenGL ES 2.0 is available.